# Joomla 3.2.0 - is it possible for Facebook comment for each article?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, joomla, comments

So i was wondering around with Joomla and noticed that is it possible for facebook default plugin code that could comment box for each articles. I've been searching for and hour or two. But no luck. There is one plugin for facebook comment. But i have to paste this `{fcomment}` in every article that i make. So it's not so good or little troubling.

And what i wnat is this kind of code:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http:// example . com/index.php?option=com_content&id=" data-width="470" data-num-posts="2"></div>
```

So is it possible to do this just by editing this code? or is there any other solution that can help me.

Thanks

Comment: I'd use the afterDisplayContent event rather than pasting in each article. Also Joomla has a JFacebook class which would probably help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For unique comments for each page you just need to change

```
data-href="http:// example . com/index.php?option=com_content&id="
```

for new data-href there is new comment box.

Pass url of page in href and it will fetch that page's comments only

Comment: data-href="<?=JURI::current()?>" replace it with current href

Answer (score 0):

yes its possible. use the al facebook comment plugin. here is the link http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-comments/16890